# Creating objects with constructor inside array literal

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to create a object using my constructor Person, but it doesn't work when I initialize the object directly in the array that uses literal notation.

```
function Person (name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
} 

var family = [
    [ new Person("alice", 40)   ],
    [ new Person("bob", 42)     ],
    [ new Person("michelle", 8) ],
    [ new Person("timmy", 6)    ]
];

for (var person in family) {
    console.log(family[person].name);
}
```

But it just prints `undefined` four times.

I gotta use this notation:

```
var family = new Array();
family[0] = new Person("alice", 40);
family[1] = new Person("bob", 42);
family[2] = new Person("michelle", 8);
family[3] = new Person("timmy", 6);
```

So it prints `alice`, `bob`, `michelle`, `timmy`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you don't want to use the plain `for` loop, you can just as easily throw it into a `forEach`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use this:

```
var family = [
     new Person("alice", 40),
     new Person("bob", 42),
     new Person("michelle", 8),
     new Person("timmy", 6)    
];
```

There isn't any need of enclosing each `Person` in brackets.

Now you can loop through the items of your array like below:

```
for (var index=0; index<family.length; index++) {
    console.log(family[index].name);
}
```

I didn't use the `for..in` since this exists for another reason:

> The for..in statement iterates over the enumerable properties of an
>   object, in arbitrary order. For each distinct property, statements can
>   be executed.

For more detais about `for...in`, please have a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in).

```js
function Person (name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
} 

var family = [
         new Person("alice", 40),
         new Person("bob", 42),
         new Person("michelle", 8),
         new Person("timmy", 6)    
    ];

for (var index=0; index<family.length; index++) {
    document.write(family[index].name);
    document.write("</br>");
}
```

Comment: But does it make my code wrong? It should run anyway, I think.

Comment: Yup, it does, because using the extra brackets you define an array in your array. Each person get inserted in an array and all these arrays are inserted in the array called family. I don't think that's your intention.

Comment: Your code runs, but you look for the property "name" on an array, not on a Person. 

see this JSBin: http://jsbin.com/doyabi/edit?js,console

Comment: @Pjetr please try to run the code snippet. Furthermore, I suggested Pedro to not define his array as he has already done. There isn't any need for inner arrays.

Comment: Yes, i know, and your answer should be marked as the correct one :)    

I merely provided the JSBin to illustrate that @pedroMelo's code runs, just not how he imagined it.

Comment: @Pjetr ok. not a problem all dude :)

Answer (score 1):

You're actually creating a 2D array - I think you only want a regular array, then use a regular `for` loop to iterate:

```
var family = [
    new Person("alice", 40), //omit the inner arrays, etc./.
];

for (var i = 0; i < family.length; i++) { 
    //check em out
    console.log(family[i].name);
}
```

Comment: Why did you use a different `for`? The one I used is not recommended?

Comment: @PedroMelo -- Yeah - the `for in` syntax if for iterating over object properties. You have an array of objects, so use a regular `for` for the array.

Comment: @PedroMelo You could also use `family.forEach(function (person) {console.log(person.name);});`